# React : Cannot set property 'animation' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list in React where I'm using `.map` to render a loop from an array of elements.

The radio inputs are working perfectly, everyone is independent of the others, but I can't do the same for `Select`.

The `Select` area is changing in every field, I want it to change to it specified field like I did for the options.

I tried to re-use the same `handleChange` that I used in the radios for it and instead I had this error.

```
Cannot set property 'animation' of undefined
```

In this line

```
newAnimations[indexurl].animation = name;
```

**How do I manage to separate the `selects` ?
Note: This code is working fine, but it's updating the value on every field.**

```
  const onChange = (animations) => {
    setAnimations(animations);
    console.log(`Animation selected:`, animations);
  };
```

Code :
https://codesandbox.io/s/dank-violet-jibzh?file=/src/App.js:1065-1194

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

export default () => {
  const animationsList = [
    { value: "animation0", label: "Dance" },
    { value: "animation1", label: "Flip" },
    { value: "animation2", label: "Salsa" }
  ];

  const reactList = [
    {
      id: "14444",
      selected: "layout3",
      animation: "animation1"
    },
    {
      id: "24444",
      selected: "layout3",
      animation: "animation2"
    },
    {
      id: "34444",
      selected: "layout3",
      animation: "animation1"
    }
  ];

  const [links, setLinks] = useState(reactList);
  const [animations, setAnimations] = useState(animationsList[0]);

  const handleChangeSelectedReact = (indexurl, layout) => {
    const cloneLinks = [...links];
    cloneLinks[indexurl].selected = layout;
    setLinks(cloneLinks);
    console.log(cloneLinks);
  };

  /* const onChange = (animations) => {
    setAnimations(animations);
    console.log(`Animation selected:`, animations);
  };*/

  const onChange = (indexurl, name) => {
    const newAnimations = [...links];
    newAnimations[indexurl].animation = name;
    setAnimations(newAnimations);
    console.log(newAnimations);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {links.map((url, indexurl) => (
            <li key={url.id}>
              <div>
                <Select
                  options={animationsList}
                  onChange={onChange}
                  value={animations}
                />
                <p />{" "}
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={url.id}
                  name={url.id}
                  value="layout1"
                  checked={url.selected === "layout1"}
                  onChange={() =>
                    handleChangeSelectedReact(indexurl, "layout1")
                  }
                />
                <label for="huey">Option 1</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={url.id}
                  name={url.id}
                  value="layout2"
                  checked={url.selected === "layout2"}
                  onChange={() =>
                    handleChangeSelectedReact(indexurl, "layout2")
                  }
                />
                <label for="dewey">Option 2</label>
              </div>
              <div>
                <input
                  type="radio"
                  id={url.id}
                  name={url.id}
                  value="layout3"
                  checked={url.selected === "layout3"}
                  onChange={() =>
                    handleChangeSelectedReact(indexurl, "layout3")
                  }
                />
                <label for="louie">Option 3</label>
              </div>
              <br />
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Your `onChange` didn't pass the `indexurl`. It should be `<Select options={animationsList} onChange={() => onChange(indexurl, "name")} value={animations} />`

Comment: @bcjohn Now all the fields become empty with `name` as value for `animation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple Selects share the same state, resulting in updates the value on every field. So we need to wrap Select into components and maintain their own state independently：

```js
function SelectItem({ list }) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(list[0]);
  const onChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return <Select options={list} onChange={onChange} value={value} />;
}
```

```
...
...
  return (
    <div>
      {links.map((url, indexurl) => (
           
         <SelectItem list={animationsList} />
      
       ))}
    </div>
  );
...
...
```

**Update**

Modify the `links` when `select` is selected:

```js
function SelectItem(props) {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(props.list[0]);

  return (
    <Select
      options={props.list}
      onChange={(newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
        props.onChange(newValue.value);
      }}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

```
...
...
  const onChange = (index, animation) => {
    const cloneLinks = [...links];
    cloneLinks[index].animation = animation;
    setLinks(cloneLinks);
    console.log(cloneLinks);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {links.map((url, indexurl) => (
           
          <SelectItem
             onChange={(animation) => onChange(indexurl, animation)}
             list={animationsList}
          />
      
       ))}
    </div>
  );
...
...
```

> Full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cloud-m6z99?file=/src/App.js:77-298

Comment: Thank you very much. But now that the fields are working, the list still returns the same `values` for animation, and not the new ones ..

Comment: you want to modify the `links` state when select is selected？@AlyaKra

Comment: Yes. I want the new list to return the updated value of `animation`

Comment: @AlyaKra, I have updated the above answer, or check the [full code](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cloud-m6z99?file=/src/App.js:77-298)

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very very much. As a beginner in React, do you have some useful documentation I can follow ? I'm really struggling.

Comment: I recommand the [React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), especially this section [Think in react](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) that shows us how to think in react way when we create UI component.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, how to set the `defaultvalue` for each fields. I know they have there default values in the array but they don't show at first.

Comment: Since you set the `value` for each field, you can try to delete it and see what happens.

Comment: It's alright I figured out how. By adding  `value={animationsList.find((aL) => aL.value === url.animation)}` to `SelectItem`